# Cloud SQL Connection with Kubernetes/Proxy Side Car

Tags: go, kubernetes, google-cloud-sql, google-kubernetes-engine, cloud-sql-proxy

Ive got a Pod with a Golang binary running an REST API. There's a side car in the pod for the gce cloud SQL proxy.

I'm constantly getting a "`dial tcp 127.0.0.1:3306: connect: connection refused`" error

The Proxy to CloudSQL connectivity is working, I can successfully connect via the cloud shell with the same credentials.

In the pod, I've also added the mysql client and I can connect to my database, so I think the credentials and everything are OK, I've proved the proxy to cloudsql connection works and can query the database

I have the following;

- Golang binary from 1.10
- Kubernetes Engine on Google Cloud
- Cluster Version: 1.10.2-gke.3
- Binary runs on top of an alpine:latest container
- Current SQL Libary is https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql
- GCE Cloud Proxy Latest and 1.11
- Credentials added as environment variables are correct user:password@tcp:host:port/DATABASE
- code uses get `os.Getenv` for env variables
- Used this as the reference: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-kubernetes-engine
- Cloud SQL instance is up and running
- secrets are created in kube and mounted as volumes too

The only change prior to this working a few months back during an previous test was the addition of services to the kubernetes deployment, and running the deployment and everything in a namespace called alpha, not default. The credential are created and everything in the name space.

Comment: Please I would like to take a further look to this issue. I work for Google Cloud Support. Could you please open a private issue, an add your project number: issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187164 Please post a new comment with the issue ID and once we found the solution I will post it here so anyone can have the answer.

Comment: Thank you! Created the issue over there. :)

Comment: It is easier to follow developments in the twin public issue tracker issue https://issuetracker.google.com/109918865 .

Comment: I believe there was a wait added with the sidecar proxy that ended up fixing this..